# iDRAC 9 Firmware Upgrade issue

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

When updating a Dell Poweredge R640 to the most recent Firmware version I am running into the following error:

*Unable to complete the firmware update operation because the specified firmware image is for a component that is not in the target system inventory*

I have updated the BIOS to the latest version, however I am still getting the same error. This is a supported download straight from the compatibility page for the service tag.

I have restarted the iDRAC controller multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because the iDRAC firmware installer places a RAM drive onto the host operating system in order to extract and run the firmware upgrade. If you previously ran an upgrade, you must clear this RAM drive for subsequent upgrades to be successful.

In order to clear this RAM drive, you either need to wait ~18 hours or do a "Cold Boot" of the system.

Once the cold boot completes, you should be able to successfully upgrade to the latest iDRAC firmware version